# Android device not recognized by adb on Windows

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I am having a problem where no devices are being recognized by adb on my system. I have tried with multiple android devices through USB. These devices have also been tested to connect properly to adb on other pcs.

I have adb kill-server then adb kill-server. Rebooted PC, rebooted devices.

I have ensured my usb driver is installed. I am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Is the `usb debugging` enabled on the devices?

Comment: Have you tried to run adb as root?

Comment: Yes usb debugging is enabled on devices. All were tested to connect properly to adb on other pc. I have not ran as root, isn't that only linux?

Comment: i'm interested in a solution since i have the same problem with my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to upgrade your adb, the old adb is not going to recognize the new devices.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. sdk tools are current release.